# cast yourself as an extra in (somthing), (by doing something)

Tags: meaning, expressions, word-usage

Would you please help me with this sentence:

where you can cast yourself as an extra in (somthing), (by doing something).

I could not fine the meaning of (cast yourself an extra..) by searching..

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extra_(acting)):

> A background actor or **extra** is a performer in a film, television show, stage, musical, opera or ballet production, who appears in a nonspeaking or nonsinging (silent) capacity, usually in the background (for example, in an audience or busy street scene).

To *cast yourself as an extra* means to give yourself a background part.